# Allow multiple gets for synchronized getter/setter

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

A common way of gaining access to a field is to synchronize the getters and setters. A simple example with an int would look like:

```
private int foo = 0;
public synchronized int get(){return this.foo;}
public synchronized void set(int bar){ this.foo = bar;}
```

Now, while this is a safe way of making the access thread safe, it also reveals that only one thread can read `foo` at a time.

If many threads where to read `foo` very often, and only sometimes update this variable, it would be a big waste. The getter instead could be called by multiple threads simultaneously without any problem.

Are there any established patterns about how to deal with this? Or how would you get around this in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).  This interface is what you are looking for, it allows for mutliple readers but only one writer.

An example:

```
private int foo = 0;

private ReadWriteLock rwLock = /* use some implementation of ReadWriteLock here */;

public int get() {
    Lock l = rwLock.readLock();
    int result = 0;
    l.lock();
    try {
        result = this.foo;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // may throw the Exception here
    }
    finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
    return result;
}

public void set(int bar){ 
    Lock l = rwLock.writeLock();
    l.lock();
    try {
        this.foo = bar;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // may throw the Exception here
    }
    finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the thing I was searching for :). Although doesn't the synchronized methods in your example defeat the purpose of the lock, or have I misunderstood how synchronized works?

Comment: @Chippen You are correct.  I forgot to remove the modifiers.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just setting and getting the variable: Then you can use `volatile` and remove `synchronized` method.

If you are doing any operations on the integer like addition you should use `AtomicInteger`.

**EDIT:**

If there is a scenario that the field is read multiple times and updated few times then there is a pattern called [IMMUTABLE](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-immutable-class-object-java-example-tutorial.html). This is one of the way to achieve thread safety.

```
class ImmutableClass{
        private final int a;

        public ImmutableClass(int a) {
            this.a  = a;
        }

        public int getA(){
            return a;
        }

        /* 
         * No setter methods making it immutable and Thread safe
         */
    }
```

For more detailed knowledge on Immutability, [Java Concurrency In practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is the best resource I would suggest you to read.

For more advanced ways: There is a [Read/Write lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: This is only and example to illustrate the problem, the content might be more complex and not be suited for atomic operations. The fact that a read method is thread safe in itself would still hold true.

Comment: You should see [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more information on this.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I hope that answers what you are looking for :)

Comment: Yes the Read/Write lock seems like a good solution to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Just wanted to point out that once you feel you have got an answer you are happy with you need to mark that answer as "accepted". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah thanks, I am not a frequent contributor on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

For examples as simple as yours, where there is only a single field and no complicated logic in the setter to really demand mutual exclusion, you can just declare the field to be `volatile` and remove the `synchronized` keywords.

For more complicated stuff, you can use the Cheap Read-Write Lock pattern:

```
public class CheapReadWriteLockPattern {

  // SINGLE-FIELD:
  private volatile Object obj;

  public Object read() {
    return obj;
  }

  public synchronized void write(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  // MULTI-FIELD:
  private static class Ref {
    final Object x;
    final Object y;
    final Object z;

    public Ref(Object x, Object y, Object z) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
    }
  }

  private volatile Ref ref = new Ref(null, null, null);

  public Object readX() { return ref.x; }
  public Object readY() { return ref.y; }
  public Object readZ() { return ref.z; }

  public synchronized void writeX(Object x) {
    ref = new Ref(x, ref.y, ref.z);
  }
  public synchronized void writeY(Object y) {
    ref = new Ref(ref.x, y, ref.z);
  }
  public synchronized void writeZ(Object z) {
    ref = new Ref(ref.x, ref.y, z);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this Cheap Read-Write Lock pattern hold any advantages over the library Read/Write Lock mentioned in the answers by Viktor and Narendra?

Comment: @Chippen Yes, readers will never starve writers. Plus, volatile reads and writes are cheaper than the lock operations. It also does not cause object allocations in the read case.